# Какой параметр отвечает за блокировку фонового окна при появление диалогового? JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, gui

Когда мы создаём какое либо диалоговое окно встроенными средствами в JavaFX, то мы не можем никаким образом контактировать с окном, из которого оно было создано, т.е. оно временно блокируется, пока диалоговое окно не будет закрыто. На данный момент я хочу сделать так, чтобы по нажатию на кнопку у меня появлялось новое полноценное окно настроек(не важно чего) и пока оно активно, то пользователь не должен никак контактировать с окном родителем как в случае с диалоговом окном. Планирую делать по [этому](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15041760/javafx-open-new-window), хотя по идее можно просто скопировать запуск основного окна и запустить по нему поменяв FXML файл(вроде).

Update
Вот пока ждал ответа нашёл [это](http://o7planning.org/ru/11533/opening-a-new-window-in-javafx). Это то?

Comment: Судя по статье, `Modelity.WINDOW_MODAL` (и `Modelity.APPLICATION_MODAL`) действительно должно дать желаемый результат.

Answer (score 0):

```
        // Specifies the modality for new window.
        newWindow.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);

        // Specifies the owner Window (parent) for new window
        newWindow.initOwner(primaryStage);
```

Modelity.WINDOW_MODAL   Когда вы открываете новое окно с этой модальностью (modelity), новое окно блокирует родительское окно. Вы не можете интерактировать с родительским окном, до тех пор, пока это окно не закроется. Источник [это](http://o7planning.org/ru/11533/opening-a-new-window-in-javafx).